# iframe is not working android inbuild browser how can resolve issue?

Tags: android, html, cordova, browser

I am working on a cross platform mobile application using phonegap (html,javascript) problem is selected item related image not display in iframe and this image display another page please see below code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onchangeevent(mySelect) 
{ 
PageIndex2=mySelect.selectedIndex; 
{ 
if  
( 
mySelect.options[PageIndex2].value != "none" 
) 
{ 
frames['iframe2'].location.href = mySelect.options[PageIndex2].value; 
} 

} 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form name="form"> 
  <p><select NAME="selectimage" SIZE="1" onChange="onchangeevent(this.form.selectimage)"> 
    <option VALUE="none" SELECTED>Select a page and go</option> 
    <option VALUE="ic_launcher.png">one</option> 
     <option VALUE="icon.png">two</option> 
  </select> </p> 
  <p> 
    <iframe src="" name="iframe2" height="100%" width="100%">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
 </p> 

</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

iframe tag not working android inbuild browser how can resolve the issue ? please tell any alternative tags supported all browsers.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android browser supports `iframe`. I suspect it's one of the other attributes that may be causing an issue. I know scroll attribute can cause the `iframe` to not appear. Try a simpler version of the iframe with just the `href` and a `width` and `height` and see if it appears.

[image: Select One]

[image: Select Two]

Comment: hi i am change the code and checking  inbuild browser is not working remaing web browsers its working fine.

Comment: What Android OS are you testing on?

Comment: i am using ApiLevel 15 (Android 4.0.3)

Comment: I just test it on 4.0.3 using [this url](http://customizedby.me/testiframe.html) it works on my device. I simply copy pasted your code, didn't change a thing. See attached screenshots.

Comment: i am test emulator android 4.0.3 its not working i am add any code or plugin please give me suggestion

Comment: I test it on the real thing, rest assured that it will work. If you need to "see" it for development them try using Dolphin browser or Opera for Android. I dont know if these will work better on the emulator. Finally, you dont need the latest greatest device to do this, just get any android device you have and develop on it, anything 2.2 and above should be good enough.

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it, the i-frame is working, it's most likely the select script, try using radio buttons see if that works.

For some reason several types of browsers are picky with the select form.