# Iframe support on mobile

Tags: android, html, mobile, jquery-mobile, windows-mobile

Is there are any ambiguity while using iFrame on the mobile devices?
Does all mobile devices support iFrame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ideally all mobile devices should support iFrame however situation can leads you to some known issues which are mentioned in below links.

You can put `<iframe src="page-1.htm" name="test" height="120" width="600">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>`  code in your page and test on various platform.

Following are known issues.

1. [iframe is not working android inbuild browser how can resolve issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187920/iframe-is-not-working-android-inbuild-browser-how-can-resolve-issue)
2. http://androidforums.com/android-applications/7101-android-browser-iframe-question.html
3. http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?843814-Iphone-iframe-browser-crash-issue-anyone

For alternate you can also try [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) if that suits your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, how exactly is jQuery Cycle relevant?