# How to run a block of code in background in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a Mobile Application using Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap. I am using a *Single Page Model*, whereby I have something like index.html, login.html etc

I have written a javascript that always contact the server side for new messages every 5 minutes using `setInterval()` and all works well in background without interfering with what the user is doing.

I want to ask if it is possible to declare and run this block of code globally instead of having to re-declare it in every html page.

Note: I am using `rel="external"` in the links in jQuery Mobile which causes each page to refresh when a user navigate to a page.

Comment: Each document must refer to the script you run. If you didn't place your code inside js file and use `<sctipt type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>`. I can't seem to find other solution.

Comment: @Michał it does, and I currently do that. What I really want is a block of codes that can run in the background regardless of the page the user navigated to.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's the only solution when using multi-page system. Each time page is reloaded so is JavaScript.

Comment: when you navigate to a different HTML file with `rel=external`, page will reload completely, thus, `setInterval()` will reset. If you load pages via Ajax (w/o `rel=external`) `setInterval()` will keep running in background.

Comment: Yes, I need to set rel="external" because I have a custom CSS style embedded in the page and without a full page reload, the style won't be implemented.

Comment: Even if this was possible, you would have another issue: timer functions are not called when the device is in sleep mode.

Comment: There is a plugin that keep the Apps alive even when the Apps is not active. That is, the Apps is never existed and run in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Android Background Service to achieve what I wanted. I used a plugin with PhoneGap. For those who want to use similar technique, you can get the info about the plugin on [phonegap-service-tutorial-part-1](http://red-folder.blogspot.com/2012/09/phonegap-service-tutorial-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your main concern is that when another script gets loaded it overwrites the previous timer so if there was one minute remaining until next call, now there are 5. To overcome this obstacle you could add a kind of logic to your interval in order to run at specific times of the day, eg 9.00, 9.05, 9.10... In this way you should clearInterval every time your script gets executed and reset it so that the next time your code gets executed is the standard time calculated against the browsers date time.

Comment: I think you are up to something here, I will consider this

Answer (score 0):

I guess u can use web workers for this purpose, they work within a global context and independently , like threads , and they are really efficient which allows you to even perform I/O.

Please check this link, Hope this helps you

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/SMMEwYXUjCU

Comment: I have checked it out and it seems whenever I moved from a page to another page, it stops to execute

Answer (score 0):

It will be more feasible if you  use the concept of `MVC` in your project . Try to make a base class which is used by the other classes . you can use the concept of `jquery widget` too

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work...

1. Creating a page (master page) that its only job is to run a timer...
2. On the master page add an iframe (set to 100% visibility) and point the iframe to your other pages...

What this will do, is that everytime one of your pages (in the iframe) postback, the master page will be kept in memory and the timer will not get reloaded...

Sample **master** page.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function checkMessages() {
    // check messages here
    setInterval(...);
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="checkMessages();">
     <iframe id="iframe1" src="subpage.aspx" width="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="100%"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have not used Iframe in Jquery Mobile before, is it possible?

Comment: All modern browsers support iframes (including [the android browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389228/iframe-support-on-mobile))...