# embedded video doesn't work on my mobile phone(android) while playing perfectly on a PC

Tags: android, video, mobile

I use below code to embed the youtube video on a web page:

```
<iframe width="290" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JyqkFKBmCBc" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It works perfectly on my PC but don't play on my smart phone. I also tried to test it using bluestacks but nothing works.

The url of the page is http://teamtuckaway.com/worth
Can anyone please visit the url to check if the video plays on your mobile phone?

The video on the page https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo doesn't play on my smart phone and bluestacks too.

I've searched sstackoverflow but can not find useful answer for me.

P.S.:Other codes I tried but not working too:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="290" height="180" style="max-width:100%;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JyqkFKBmCBc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: Found some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Iframe support on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389228/iframe-support-on-mobile)

Apparently a lot of mobile devices just don't support iFrames.